# Search Parameter in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I am wondering if it is possible to create a cyrsal parameter that will search a given column in a table based on the string parameter values.

Lets says if I provide Purchase Order string value as a parameter it will look to Table1.ref1 (string field) which has any lines with Purchase order, Purchase Order,purchase Order, purchase order (taking care of upper and lower cases)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your selection formula:

```
if instr(lowercase({Table1.ref1}),lowercase({?PO_Parm}))>0 then true
```